# Spring Web Application 404 Not Found Error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I am building a spring based java web application. I am receiving a 404 not found exception when I try to launch the root of the web application:

This is my configuration:

web.xml

[image]

spring-servlet.xml

[image]

controller inside com.myapp.controllers package

[image]

I have an index.jsp file inside of the /WEB-INF/jsp folder.

Any help would be appreciated.
I am running the application from Eclipse against a Tomcat 8.5 instance.
The 404 error is at http://localhost:8080/customer-webapp

Comment: Share the output you see on your jsp when you hit (ONLY) - http://localhost:8080

Comment: What is your specific reason for not using Spring Boot?

Comment: what does <tomcat-home>/webapps folder look like? does it have customer-webapp folder?